# Math inside a bag

Tags: apache-pig

I have bags of tuples, and one field in each bag needs to be normalized to zero.  I take the `MIN` of that field over the bag, and subtract that min from each tuple.

> Can this be done **without flattening**?

The actual situation is slightly more complicated, because I only want the min over a subset of the tuples meeting a certain condition.

Here's some sample code which doesn't work:

```
data = LOAD 'data.csv' USING PigStorage(',')
    AS (x:int, y:int, z:int);

data_grouped = GROUP data BY x;

data_normal = FOREACH data_grouped {
    good_data = FILTER data BY y == 0;
    smallest_good_z = MIN(good_data.z);
    GENERATE data.(x, y, z-smallest_good_z);
}

DESCRIBE data_normal;

rmf data_normal
STORE data_normal INTO 'data_normal' USING PigStorage(',');
```

and a sample `data.csv`:

```
0,0,1
0,0,2
0,0,3
0,1,0
0,2,-1
1,2,3
1,3,4
1,4,5
1,0,5
```

Please tell me I don't have to group, `MIN`, flatten, subtract, and regroup!  Here's the method I'm using now, which I want to get away from:

```
data = LOAD 'data.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS
    (x:int, y:int, z:int);

data_grouped = GROUP data BY x;

data_n0 = FOREACH data_grouped {
    good_data = FILTER data BY y == 0;
    smallest_good_z = MIN(good_data.z);
    GENERATE FLATTEN(data.(x, y, z)), smallest_good_z AS smz:int;
}

data_n1 = FOREACH data_n0 GENERATE x,y,z-smz;

data_normal = GROUP data_n1 BY x;
```

Comment: Oh there's a cat pun lurking somewhere in the title of the question... :D

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can do it only with UDF. Here is an example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.DataBag;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;

public class MinusToAllInBag extends EvalFunc<Tuple> {

    @Override
    public Tuple exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null || input.size() != 3) {
            System.err.println("Inputs are ({inputBag}, position, toSubtract)");
            return null;
        }
        try {
            Object o = input.get(0);
            if (!(o instanceof DataBag)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("parameter 1 must be a databag");
            }
            DataBag inputBag = (DataBag)o;
            Integer pos = (Integer) input.get(1);
            Float toSubtract = (Float) input.get(2);
            for (Tuple row : inputBag) {
                Float value = (Float)row.get(pos);
                if (value != null) {
                    value -= toSubtract;
                    row.set(pos, value);
                }
            }
            return input;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to process input; error - " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And the pig script:

```
REGISTER libs.jar;

data = LOAD 'data.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS
    (x:int, y:int, z:float);

data_grouped = GROUP data BY x;

data_n0 = FOREACH data_grouped {
    good_data = FILTER data BY y == 0;
    smallest_good_z = MIN(good_data.z);
    GENERATE group, MinusToAllInBag(data, 2, (float)smallest_good_z);
}

dump data_n0;
```

Comment: Can this UDF approach be extended to work on a bag of tuples where you don't know the size of the tuple?  In other words, always subtract a value from the n-th position in any tuple, no matter if it has n fields or n+1000 fields?  In my situation I really cannot keep a UDF which needs to be edited every time I add a field to my tuple.

Comment: Yes, it is the second argument to the UDF, the first one is the BAG, pos in the BAG tuple starting with 0, number to subtract. At this moment all numbers must be float. As per example index 2 in the "MinusToAllInBag(data, 2, (float)smallest_good_z)" is the 3rd column if you count starts from 1.